# TabHost\WebView embedded youtube video float issue

Tags: android, webview, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost with 3 TabSpecs. One tab is using a WebView and when I load a url that has an embedded youtube video and then click on another tab, the youtube video floats above its containing tab and is visible on subsequent tabs. I need the video to NOT be visible when another tab is selected.

[Screenshot](http://www.jaydial.net/android/android_youtube_float.jpg)

The application is built using this tutorial : "http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html"

I have modified the ArtistsActivity to use a WebView:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ArtistsActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView view = new WebView(this);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        view.loadUrl("http://www.jaydial.net/android/youtube.htm");
        setContentView(view);

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);        
            return true;
        }
     } 
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

JayDial

Answer (score 1):

Just load a blank string into the webview when you leave the current tab.

webview.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");

http://yue-gao.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-trick-for-stop-video-when-leave.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I came up with this solution also. Its working for the time being, but i am trying to prevent reloading the page if it has already been loaded.